# Obteniendo los registros de un asociación en un collection en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Saludos! Estoy intentando obtener los municipios de una asociación en un collection, sin embargo estoy teniendo dificultades, los municipios son una asociación entre empresas y municipios, por lo tanto, me gustaría que él collection imprima los municipios asociados a las empresas que publican esos trabajos, para hacer más sencillo, colocar la asociación actual:

```
Municipality.rb
has_many :enterprises

Enterprise.rb
belongs_to :muncipality
has_many :jobs

Job.rb
belongs_to :enterprise
```

Si job estuviera asociado directamente a Municipality podria facilmente obtenerlo de la siguiente manera, usando un scope, sin embargo quiero sacar provecho de la empresas, mi codigo aqui:

**job.rb**

```
scope :municipality, -> (municipality_id) { where(municipality_id: municipality_id) }
```

**jobs_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    if params[:municipality_id].present?
      @jobs = Job.municipality(params[:municipality_id]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)      
    else
      @jobs = Job.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
    end
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag({ controller: :jobs, action: :index }, { method: :get }) do %>
  <div class="input-group no-margin">
    <%= select_tag(:municipality_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Municipality.all, :id, :name), { :include_blank => "Todos los municipios", class: "input-group-field" }) %>
    <div class="input-group-button">
      <%= button_tag( :class => "button secondary", name: nil ) do %>
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que no exista una asociación directa entre `Job` y `Municipality` no implica que no se pueda utilizar `municipality_id` con el modelo `Job`, simplemente debes hacer un *JOIN* con el modelo `Enterprise`, lo que te dará acceso al municipio a través de `enterprises.municipality_id`.

Considerando lo anterior, el `scope` en `Job` se vería así:

```
scope :municipality, -> (municipality_id) { 
  joins(:enterprise).where("enterprises.municipality_id = ?", municipality_id)
}
```

Claro que, dado que estás construyendo manualmente el `where`, podrías omitir el nombre de la tabla `enterprises`, pues la columna `municipality_id` únicamente se encuentra en esa tabla; por ejemplo:

```
scope :municipality, -> (municipality_id) { 
  joins(:enterprise).where("municipality_id = ?", municipality_id)
}
```

Es importante destacar que **no** puedes utilizar algo como

```
joins(:enterprise).where(municipality_id: municipality_id)
```

ya que *ActiveRecord* automáticamente agregará la tabla `jobs` a `municipality_id` (i.e. `jobs.municipality.id`) y el *query* te devolverá un error.

Comment: Mas que perfecto no lo pudistes explicar Gerry! Siempre preciso! Agradezco muchisimo tu ayuda!